# Unable to change volume during call when on speaker mode

Tags: iphone, speakers, call

I'm able to change volume when not on speaker, however it does not work if I'm on speaker mode. (see image below). Bluetooth is turned off for what it's worth so it should not be trying to redirect to some other device.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Visited Apple store and ended up fixing the issue by "Reset all Settings".